# jquery tablesorter pager , top and bottom pagination links

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-pagination

I am working on a project, it has has pagination using jquery.tablesorter.pager.
It has pagination links on top. now i want to add same link to bottom as well.
I tried adding pager div at bottom, but it doesnt work. any help appreciated.

Comment: post some code and how is this relevant to CI? are you using CI's paginate class?

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion you can try using the same pager but make it appear at the top or bottom as required when scrolling.

i added 2 divs as placeholders to my page above and below the table:

```
    <div id="PagerTop">
    </div>
    <table id="mytable" class="tablesorter">
    </table>
    <div id="PagerBottom">
    </div>
```

Then i added JQuery functions to check if the pager element is in view:

```
// Check if the element is in view
function isScrolledIntoViewBottom(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var my_elem_offset = $(elem).offset(); //Need to check the offset first as there is a bug in IE
    if (my_elem_offset === null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
        return (elemBottom >= docViewTop);
    }
}

// Check if the element is in view
function isScrolledIntoViewTop(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var my_elem_offset = $(elem).offset(); //Need to check the offset first as there is a bug in IE
    if (my_elem_offset === null) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
        return (elemTop <= docViewBottom);
    }
}
```

Add this script to the top of the page to check the pager position when scrolling:

```
     // When scrolling always make sure that the Pager for the table in view 
    // is either at the top or bottom of the table.
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (!isScrolledIntoViewBottom('#pager')) {
            $("#pager").appendTo("#PagerBottom");
        }
        if (!isScrolledIntoViewTop('#pager')) {
            $("#pager").appendTo("#PagerTop");
        }
    });
```

Also, you can set the default position on intial load using this JQuery:

```
    // Set the Pagers to the top of the table on document load
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pager").appendTo("#PagerTop");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I customized the code as followa and it works perfectly.
The idea is that you put the 2 pagination codes in one div (`<div id="pager">`) and in one form (`<form name="pagination" id="pagination_id">`)
after that, you should handle some issues caused by footer pagination where Go buttons and page select don't work by default with javascript.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="pager" class="pager" >
 <form name="pagination" id="pagination_id">
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/first.png" title="" class="first"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/prev.png"  title="" class="prev"/>
     <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" name="numberofpages" onKeyPress="return handleEnter(this, event)" style="width:63px;"/>
     <input type="button" class="gotopage" id="gotoPageButton" value="GO" style="width:auto"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/next.png" title="Next" class="next"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/last.png"  title="Last page" class="last"/>
     <select class="pagesize" name="pagesize" onchange="changePageSize(this)">
                        <option selected="selected"  value="10">10 per page</option>
                        <option value="20">20 per page</option>
                        <option value="30">30 per page</option>
                        <option  value="40">40 per page</option>
                    </select>

     <table id="mytable" class="tablesorter"> blah blah</table>

     <!-- pagination footer -->
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/first.png" title="First page" class="first"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/prev.png"  title=Previous class="prev"/>
     <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" name="numberofpages2" onKeyPress="return handleEnter(this, event)" style="width:63px;"/>
     <input type="button" class="gotopage" id="gotoPageButton2" value="GO" onclick="clickGObutton()" style="width:auto"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/next.png" title="Next" class="next"/>
     <img src="addons/pager/icons/last.png"  title="Last page" class="last"/>
     <select class="pagesize" name="pagesize2" onchange="changePageSize(this)">
         <option selected="selected"  value="10">10 per page</option>
         <option value="20">20 per page</option>
         <option value="30">30 per page</option>
         <option  value="40">40 per page</option>
     </select>
 </form>
</div>
```

then the javascript functions for Go button and select:

// On ENTER key pressed on input name-numofpages then button GO is executed (the result table goes to the page selected)

```
function handleEnter (field, event) {
var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
if (keyCode == 13) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
        if (field == field.form.elements[i]) {
            break;
        }

    if (field.name == "numberofpages2") {
        document.forms["pagination"]["numberofpages"].value = field.value;
    }
    document.getElementById("gotoPageButton").click();

    return false;
} 
else
return true;}
```

//when change header select make the change on footer too. And the reverse.

```
function changePageSize(field) {
if (field.name == "pagesize") {
    document.forms["pagination"]["pagesize2"].value = field.value;
}
else if (field.name == "pagesize2") {
    document.forms["pagination"]["pagesize"].value = field.value;
}}
```

//if click the footer Go button put the footer's numofpages2 value on header's numofpages2 value and click Go button on header

```
function clickGObutton(){
document.forms["pagination"]["numberofpages"].value = document.forms["pagination"]["numberofpages2"].value
document.getElementById("gotoPageButton").click();}
```

NOTE: what happened? The footer pagination has no functionality by itself (except buttons next, previous, last, first which work fine) we just fill the fields and connect the buttons with no functionality to the header pagination (that does have functionality) to make them work.

Answer (score 0):

User the "pager" class reference in html:

```
<div class="pager">
    <span class="icon-step-backward first"></span>
    <span class="icon-backward prev"></span>
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span>
    <span class="icon-forward next"></span>
    <span class="icon-step-forward last"></span>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
</div>
<table>
    ...
</table>
<div class="pager">
    <span class="icon-step-backward first"></span>
    <span class="icon-backward prev"></span>
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span>
    <span class="icon-forward next"></span>
    <span class="icon-step-forward last"></span>
    <select class="pagesize">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Then in javascript set the pageroptions like below:

```
var pagerOptions = {
    container: $(".pager"),
    ...other options...
};
```